# Error keystore tampered with or password incorrect when building appbundle with the correct keystore passowrd

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, android-keystore, android-app-bundle

I have a problem with keystore.jks file in my flutter app,

I'm able to open the keystore.jks file with  `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks` command with the password (not any default password where you get a warning), but When trying to build appbundle It fails with error:
`Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect...`

What can I do in a situation like this?

PS: The app is not new and was already uploaded to Google Play, I had been failing at the keytool command with a wrong password for a while and I tried another password now and it worked.
Also I'm building the app on another pc than where the keystore file was generated, does that affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing how I solved maybe it helps someone else,
I was able to build appbundle with moving the credentials of the store in build.gradle rather than calling them from key.properties, even though I had the key.properties and keystore files as required.

So instead of this:

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
```

I did this:

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias 'myKey'
           keyPassword "keyPassword"
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword "storePassword"
       }
   }
```

And of course don't commit those changes to git so you don't share the credentials to the jks file.